# Finding file in MATLAB's path

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB, I have a file name (for example `'file name'`) as a string assigned to a variable `fname`. I want to find where in the MATLAB path this file can be found, if anywhere. `which(fname)` just tells me that `fname` is a variable whereas `which('file name')` gives me the path info. How can I do it with the name in a variable?

Comment: `which(fname)` should work (it can't give you "fname is a variable"). Must be a typo somewhere. `which('fname')` gives "I am a variable".

Comment: fname ='fname'; Then which(fname) returns "fname is a variable."

Comment: @JoeSerrano - Yeah that'll do it.  In that case, the OP needs to use another name as the variable instead of using the string and the variable to be the same name.

Answer (score 1):

`which` should also be able to take in string variables.  I'm not sure why you're just getting the variable itself.  Here's an example (on Mac OS X 10.9.3 using MATLAB R2013a):

```
fname = 'imfilter.m';
loc = which(fname)

loc =

/Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/toolbox/images/images/imfilter.m
```

However, if you encapsulate the variable as a string, it will spit out that it's a variable:

```
loc = which('fname')

loc = 

variable
```

Comment: Mea culpa. I was confusing which fname vs. which (fname). The former says fname is a variable, the latter works as you said, thanks.

Comment: @user3657408 - Haha not a problem.  Glad I / we could help.